# How does TranslateAccelerator know about CTRL or SHIFT modifier?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm working in a program that uses Accelerator keys for user-defined hot keys, and every thing works fine.  The user can set hotkeys using SHIFT, CTRL, or ALT.  I know that using ALT generates a WM_SYSKEYDOWN rather than WM_KEYDOWN, so it's pretty obvious when ALT is held down.

TranslateAccelerator only takes a window handle, the accel table handle and a single KEYDOWN message.  So, my question is, if the user presses CTRL+T, how does TranslateAccelerator know the CTRL key was also pressed?

I know that the CTRL generates a separate KEYDOWN command, and I specifically filtered those out (do not pass to TranslateAccelerator) to test a theory, but TranslateAccelerator is still working.

Comment: It probably uses GetKeyState().

Comment: I considered that, but since Windows messages are inherently asynchronous, can getting the current key state be a valid test?

Comment: Well, that's why GetKeyState() and not GetAsyncKeyState().  GetKeyState() is synchronous by using the buffered state of the keyboard.

Comment: TranslateAccelerator() calls GetKeyState(). But GetKeyState() does not obtain the CURRENT state of CTRL, ALT, SHIFT. GetKeyState() returns the state when the Windows message has been sent. So if we call TranslateAccelerator() without beeing in the Windows message handler routine this function becomes useless because it obtains the wrong key state.