# Ignoring the status of Shift key when detecting shortcuts via TranslateAccelerator

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I'm stuck: How do I prevent the virtual Shift key from being considered during accelerator translation? For instance, if my accelerator table contains a single entry of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (to select everything in currently focused window, say), then I would want the corresponding command be detected when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is pressed as well as if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is pressed (but contrary, I still want the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to play its role, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> shound't translate to my command).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31457613/how-does-translateaccelerator-know-about-ctrl-or-shift-modifier) didn't help. I think I'm calling the `TranslateAccelerator` function while I'm still in the message loop (see code below and correct me if I'm wrong).

I tried to outsmart Windows by getting the current keyboard status when I see a `WM_KEYDOWN` message, manually change the virtual Shift key status to "not pressed," do the accelerator translation, and revert my manual modifications. In code:

```
BOOL CHexaEditor::PreTranslateMessage(PMSG pMsg){
    // pre-processing the Message
    if (::GetFocus()==m_hWnd){ // I'm not sure if this is mandatory in MFC
        if (pMsg->message==WM_KEYDOWN){
            BYTE keyboardState[256];
            ::GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);
            const BYTE shiftState0=keyboardState[VK_SHIFT];
            keyboardState[VK_SHIFT]=0; // 0 = "not pressed"
                const BOOL result=::TranslateAccelerator(m_hWnd,hDefaultAccelerators,pMsg);
            keyboardState[VK_SHIFT]=shiftState0;
            ::SetKeyboardState(keyboardState);
            return result;
        }else
            return ::TranslateAccelerator(m_hWnd,hDefaultAccelerators,pMsg);
    }else
        return FALSE;
}
```

No success so far, any help highly appreciated. Thanks :-)

Comment: Can you just put entries for both `Ctrl+A` and `Ctrl+Shift+A` in the accelerator table?  I wouldn't try to hack around as you are doing in your post.

Comment: Well, this might be a way, thanks - I didn't yet think of this one :-) But I'd rather want a "cleaner hack" than this - I (or anyone else, as it's an open-source project) can derive from the MFC class, and they would need to stick to that rule of suppling also the "Shift-version" for each accelerator. Well, otherwise, they need to stick to the rule to not using Shift in their accelerators, but that's already easier manageable (imo).

Comment: Calling `SetKeyboardState` **after** `TranslateAccelerator` won't do anything. Remember that `keyboardState` is just a local copy.

Comment: I'm so stupid, thanks a lot!

Comment: IMHO, @PaulSanders "hack" is the cleanest hack for this. Why write code when you can just add an accelerator table entry?

Comment: As explained above, the Shift key must be fully ignored. If someone forgets to add the Shift-version of the shortcut, we have a problem - the app won't do anything (or the shortcut will be misinterpreted as another MFC target gets crack on the keyboard state).

Answer (score 1):

So the correct answer is (thanks to [ybungalobill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277176/ybungalobill) above):

```
BOOL CHexaEditor::PreTranslateMessage(PMSG pMsg){
    // pre-processing the Message
    if (::GetFocus()==m_hWnd){
        if (pMsg->message==WM_KEYDOWN){
            BYTE keyboardState[256];
            ::GetKeyboardState(keyboardState);
            const BYTE shiftState0=keyboardState[VK_SHIFT];
            keyboardState[VK_SHIFT]=0;
/* --> */   ::SetKeyboardState(keyboardState); // this line was missing
                const BOOL result=::TranslateAccelerator(m_hWnd,hDefaultAccelerators,pMsg);
            keyboardState[VK_SHIFT]=shiftState0;
            ::SetKeyboardState(keyboardState);
            return result;
        }else
            return ::TranslateAccelerator(m_hWnd,hDefaultAccelerators,pMsg);
    }else
        return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I think you need `if (result) return TRUE;` then return `CWnd::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg)` for all other cases.